# Getting some error while updating angular build on live

Tags: build, angular5

I'm updating my angular app as usual and today I'm getting this error.

```
ng build --prod
```

This command runs successful and also I have updated the base URL.

For check, I tried to update build 3 times and I'm getting the same error.

[image: issue image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had just face this issue recently and there is no any issue in your code or build. It's just issue of cacheing, You can clear you browser data or try to open app in private window.

By this way it solved my issue, I hope it may help you too.

Happy coding... :)